# dynamically add attributes to class in python

Tags: python, attributes

I need to dynamically add attributes to a class in python

```
download_folder = mail_box.Folders('Inbox').Folders[subfolder].Folders[subfolder]....etc
```

is it somehow possible to add a certain number of subfolders - '.Folders[subfolder]' dynamically with a loop or some sort of lambda function?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what type of object `mail_box` is.  It seems that you are not interested in generically how to add attributes to any python class, but rather how to use a specific class (or package?) to model a hierarchy of folders.  So you need to tell us more about your variable `mail_box`, such as how it works or at least where it comes from.

Comment: import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
mail_box = outlook.Folders(mbox)
download_folder = mail_box.Folders('Inbox').Folders['subfolder'].Folders['subsubfolder']

My idea is to dynamically add subfolders based on their count in an list. Is it possible?

Comment: I see now that `mail_box` is a Windows COM object.  All COM objects are different and AFAIK you have to study the Microsoft documentation to know how any specific one works.  I am not familiar with Outlook's COM model.  I think this is not so much a Python question as a COM question.  Perhaps you're more likely to get good help if you ask a more focused question about that.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. I can give a short example if it works for you.

```
class folder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subfolder=[]
```

You can create a new folder object by:

```
newfolder=folder()
```

Then you can add a new subfolder for newfolder by:

```
newsubfolder=folder()
newfolder.subfolder.append(newsubfolder)
```